# how to set showModalBottomSheet width in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, menu, widget, flutter-layout

I have the design(shown in the photo) and I'm using showModalBottomSheet but when I set the width, it doesn't change and stay as screen width, so I have a couple of questions:

1-how to set a width to showModalBottomSheet
2-is there an alternative to showModalBottomSheet for this kind of bottom menu's
3-how to blur the background as it shows in the photo

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.6,
              width: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting a container inside a container.
the parent container has a transparent color, while the child has solid color and padding.
BUT STILL i didn't figure out how to blur the background yet.
this is the code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            builder: (BuildContext bc) {
              return Container(
                height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.6,
               
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.4),
                  child: Container(
                  
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child:
                        
                          Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 1.5),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                     
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
```

Answer (score 7):

Use constraints property in showModalBottomSheet.

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth:  600,              
    ),
    builder: ...
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have custom height and width you can do this, this code will position it to the right of the screen with 50% width and 75% height.. some of the answers can do this but I added also here that if the user clicks on the left of the sheet it will pop down so it will work perfectly just like your design.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (tapDetails) {
                //closing bottom sheet on tapping on the left
                if (tapDetails.globalPosition.dx <
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
```